# Foursquare category names localization broken

Tags: localization, foursquare

There's a problem with translation of category names into local languages:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories%3Flocale%3Dru

Most of categories are now in English despite sending `locale`, though it used to work fine a week ago. Foursquare developers, please take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug.  Localization of categories is working fine now!

Comment: I managed to contact Maryam from Foursquare via LinkedIn, and they fixed it immediately, so all good now!